# Devise sign up AJAX not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I am trying to setup a registration form using devise and AJAX.
On a newly generated app it works perfectly but when I try and add it to a project, I do not have success

registration controller
https://gist.github.com/mosinski/8568126

my partial form:
https://gist.github.com/mosinski/8577429

my application.js:
https://gist.github.com/mosinski/8577480

my inicializer:
https://gist.github.com/mosinski/8577533

my application helper:
https://gist.github.com/mosinski/8577564

my form is partial in bootstrap modal.
The whole problem is that it not sending as js but as text/html why ?! ;]

Answer (score 0):

**1. Routes**

Have you declared the custom controllers in your `routes.rb` file?

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions", registrations: "registrations" }
```

**2. Forms**

Are you sure you're sending the request from your partial form?

Devise generates its own views (which you can typically find at `/views/devise`). If you're using the standard Devise forms, you'll be sending standard HTML mime-types, and so you'll have to ensure you're using your partial

That's all I can glean from your code currently! Of course we can discuss any fixes in the comments

---

**Update**

Here's our working registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  prepend_view_path 'app/views/devise'

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource

          respond_to do |format|
                format.json { render :json => resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
                format.html { respond_with resource }
          end
    end
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    render :edit
  end

  # PUT /resource
  # We need to use a copy of the resource because we don't want to change
  # the current user in place.
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    if update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
      if is_navigational_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  # DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    resource.destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed if is_navigational_format?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  def cancel
    expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
    redirect_to new_registration_path(resource_name)
  end

  protected

  # Custom Fields
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name,
        :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end

  def update_needs_confirmation?(resource, previous)
    resource.respond_to?(:pending_reconfirmation?) &&
      resource.pending_reconfirmation? &&
      previous != resource.unconfirmed_email
  end

  # By default we want to require a password checks on update.
  # You can overwrite this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_with_password(params)
  end

  # Build a devise resource passing in the session. Useful to move
  # temporary session data to the newly created user.
  def build_resource(hash=nil)
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
  end

  # Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
  # RegistrationsController.
  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  end

  # The path used after sign up. You need to overwrite this method
  # in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts. You need to overwrite
  # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    respond_to?(:root_path) ? root_path : "/"
  end

  # The default url to be used after updating a resource. You need to overwrite
  # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    signed_in_root_path(resource)
  end

  # Authenticates the current scope and gets the current resource from the session.
  def authenticate_scope!
    send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", :force => true)
    self.resource = send(:"current_#{resource_name}")
  end

  def sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up)
  end

  def account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
  end
end
```

Comment: I add right routes :) ***[link](https://gist.github.com/mosinski/8578978)***
I'm sure becouse the right parameters are sending and in devise folder there is no registration folder ;)

I'm confused firebug show post by text/html... ;/

Comment: the render is in layout
***[link](https://gist.github.com/mosinski/8579364)***
the form is in shared/sign_up_candidate
***[link](https://gist.github.com/mosinski/8577429)***

Comment: Thanks! I really meant - can you post your *rendered* content? I.E from the `view-source` tab in your browser?

Comment: Thanks! The HTML says it's `remote` - do you get any Ajax requests firing on submit? If so, what is the response from the server?

Comment: after click submit it redirecting me and last request in firebug is post as text/html and serwer says:
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-23 16:18:12 +0100
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mosinski/8568126#file-registrations_controller-rb-L30 that's the erroneous code. You need to use a `respond_to` block. I'll update my answer with our custom registrations controller (needs refactoring)